# Fivestar Field That Shows Average of Other Fivestar field

Tags: rating

> First of all, I'm quite new in Drupal 7 and I've almost Zero
>   knowledge in coding.

I've create a custom content type (Review - Machine Name: `review`) with 4 Fivestar Field :

1. Support - Machine Name: `field_support`
2. Performance - Machine Name: `field_performance`
3. Value - Machine Name: `field_value`
4. Overall - Machine Name: `field_overall`

I've also created 4 Fivestar Voting tag:

1. `rating_support`
2. `rating_value`
3. `rating_performance`
4. `rating_overall`

I want the Overall field to display the average of the other three Fivestar Field. I've followed exactly as written [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1492650#comment-8194661).

Here is the code that I've used on my `template.php`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 *
 * Hide average fivestar field from review edit/create form.
 */
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'review_node_form') {
    // Hide average field, this field is calculated upon node_presave.
    $form['field_overall']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 *
 * Calculates average vote rating.
 */
function bartik_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'review') {
    // Get values from 3 axis.
    $rating_support      = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node)->field_support->value();
    $rating_value      = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node)->field_value->value();
    $rating_performance    = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node)->field_performance->value();

    // Calculate and set average axe.
    $rating_overall      = ($rating_support + $rating_value + $rating_performance) / 3;
    // @info: Can't use entity_metadata_wrapper, because '->set' not supported on this field.
    //entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node)->field_overall->set($rating_overall);
    $node->field_overall['und'][0]['rating'] = $rating_overall;  
  }
}
```

But The overall fivestar rating field displaying 'no votes yet' after publishing content. How can I fix this, Have I done something wrong?